# Set Existence Within ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Halmos'book, an initial assumption is stated 
                         "there exists a set",

followed by the proviso that "... later on we shall formulate a a deeper and more useful existential assumption".  My questions are:

a. Is there within ZFC an axiom that actually postulates the existence of a set?

b. How is the axiom written in the object language?

c. Is there a way to prove the existence of a set from the usual axioms? If so, what are the steps in the proof?

Many thanks for all help.

Agapito

Comment: The axiom of infinity states that a set exists with some special properties.

Comment: @drhab As does the axiom of the empty set.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Indeed but that axiom is actually redundant if the axiom of infinity is accepted. Not vice versa.

Comment: There always exists something, as $\exists x (x=x)$ is true in first order logic. So no set existence axiom is needed.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus That is really interesting. I never thought of it that way.

Comment: I always find it to be a strange assumption that first order logic always requires a non-empty domain of discourse, from a model theoretic point of view.  e.g. to me the empty set should work just fine as a semigroup, and therefore as a model of the first-order language of semigroups.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, but the definition is not arbitrary, as it is connected to the theorem that a theory is consistent iff it has a model, so the nonempty requirement plays a role in that proof.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: It really is arbitrary; some deduction systems are built for only nonempty domains and others allow empty domains, and this affects what "consistent" means.

Answer (score 2):

a) The axiom of infinity is one of the axioms stated by Zermelo.

b) $\exists a\left[\exists b\left[b\in a\wedge\forall x\;x\notin b\right]\wedge\forall x\in a\;\exists y\in a\forall z\left[z\in y\Leftrightarrow z\in x\vee z=x\right]\right]$

In words: there is a set that contains as element a set that has no elements, and secondly has the property that it contains the set $a\cup\{a\}$ whenever it contains set $a$.

c) Speaks for itself. Just refer the axiom.

Comment: Would the axiom of paring do the same thing? That is, if a and b are sets, then set c exists such that  c={a,b}. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No. A pair $\{a,b\}$ will only exists if its elements $a,b$ (already) exist. Note that the axiom of infinity has quantor $\exists$ as utmost left. All other axioms start with $\forall$. Glad to help.

Comment: OK. So if any other axiom is invoked, strictly speaking, should it be prefaced by something like "'a' is a set and 'b' is a set? If so, what would be the object language sentence for this?  Your help is very useful and appreciated.

Comment: If $a$ is mentioned as propositional variable (e.g. in axiom PAIR: $\forall a\forall b\exists c\forall x[x\in c\iff[x=a\vee x=b]$) then $a$ simply *must be a set* because in set-theory everything is a set. It is not needed to use some expression that substitutes "$a$ is a set".

Comment: Many thanks again, Agapito

Comment: This site has always been very useful to me in self-learning set theory and other topics in Math.  Now apparently I can no longer post questions because of the "low quality" of my previous posts.  Is there any way I can be "re-instated"?